How can I display folders with both hidden and system attributes
I hide folders on my Windows machine using attrib +h +s d:\<filename>. Now I forgot folder names and not able to retrive hidden folders.
I tried attrib -h -s  d:, but it didn't work.

Open a Command Prompt window, typePushD D:\ 2>NUL && (Dir /A:DHS /B & PopD), and press the [ENTER] key.

On Windows 11 click in Windows File Explorer on the toolbar on item … and next in opened pop-up menu on Options. On tab View select for Hidden files and folders the option Show hidden files, folders, and drives and uncheck the option Hide protected operating system files (Recommended). All files and folders can be seen in Windows File Explorer after a click on button OK. It is advisable for a not experienced user like you to check later again Hide protected operating system files (Recommended) and select option Don't show hidden files, folders, or drives.

Run the following command in the Command Prompt to list all files and folders, including hidden and system ones, on the drive:
dir d:\ /a:h /s


/a:h: Lists hidden files and folders.
/s: Searches recursively in all subdirectories.
Reference

If you find your desired hidden folders  then try unhide command again.
attrib -h -s "d:\<foldername>"

